# Write on the next available cell of a given column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a somewhat simple macro that I have made but I am rusty as I have not coded in a few years. As simply as I can put it, I Have two different Workbooks. If the workbook I have open has a certain value (or no value), I want it to fill the other workbook("Test Template") with either "proposal or pre-proposal." 
That has all been easy for me. But since the worksheet adds rows as we input data, I need it to fill those values in the next available row.

I will attach code but don't worry about the proposal stuff, I just need the range changed from a specific cell into the next available cell in the column. (if d28 is full, put in d29).

[image: Here is a screenshot of code and the two workbooks]

```
Public Sub foo()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = ActiveWorkbook
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\hmaggio\Desktop\Test Template.xlsx")




'copy Names from x(active):
x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4").Copy

'paste to y worksheet(template):
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B28").PasteSpecial



If x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C15") = "" Then
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D28").Value = "proposal"
Else

y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D28").Value = "preproposal"


End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The object `Range` offers a method called `End` that returns the last range on a certain direction.

```
Range("A1").End(xlDown) '<-- returns the last non-empty range going down from cell A1
Range("A1").End(xlUp) '<-- same, but going up
Range("A1").End(xlToRight) '<-- same, but going right
Range("A2").End(xlToLeft) '<-- same, but going left
```

In your case, hence, you can detect and use the last row of column `B` like this:

```
nextRow = y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row + 1
```

**More details**:

- The first Range of your column B is the header `Range("B3")`
- You get the last filled range going down with `.End(xlDown)`
- Specifically, you get the `Row` of that range
- You add `+ 1` (cause you want the next available row
- You store the row in the variable `nextRow`

... that you can then use like this:

```
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & nextRow ).PasteSpecial
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a variable where you'll store the last used row number:

```
dim lngRows as long
lngRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
```

Then replace your lines of code where you have `.Range("B28")` with either `.Cells(lngRows+1,2)` or `.Range("B"&lngRows)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Public Sub foo()

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim fromWs As Worksheet
    Dim toWs As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Range

    '## Open both workbooks first:
    Set x = ActiveWorkbook
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\hmaggio\Desktop\Test Template.xlsx")


    Set fromWs = x.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set toWs = y.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With fromWs
        Set Target = toWs.Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) '<~~next row Column B cell
        Target = .Range("c4") 'Column B
        If .Range("c15") = "" Then
            Target.Offset(, 2) = "proposal" 'Column D
        Else
            Target.Offset(, 2) = "preproposal"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```